# Confusing Description for readObjectOverride and writeObjectOverride

Tags: java, serialization, java-io, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I was reading through the documentation for `java.io` when I noticed that the description of `ObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride()` said this:

> "This method is called by trusted subclasses of **ObjectOutputStream**..."

and that the description of `ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride()`said this:

> "This method is called by trusted subclasses of **ObjectInputStream**...".

(emphasis mine for both quotes above)

I've serialized objects before, but never subclassed `ObjectInputStream` or `ObjectOutputStream`. Why would subclasses of `ObjectInputStream` need to call `writeObjectOverride` as opposed to `readObjectOverride`, and vice versa?

Comment: It's a typo, or two typos.

Comment: I suspected that, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride seems totally broken. It's use case is such that it's invoked only when ObjectOutputStream is created with no parameters. This means you can't call any methods that would actually write anything.

I can't think of a use case for it at all.